# Editing content of legend in TeeChart

Tags: delphi, teechart

Is it possible to programatically edit teh legend in a TeeChart, so the variables called with the left axis and right axis can be distinguished. To illustrate:

If I am plotting three series p, q, and r, and p and q use VertAxis := aLeftAxis, while r uses VartAxis := aRightAxis, then in the legend I want to group p, and q under a left axis heading and r under a right axis heading. Alternately, two separate legends would suffice to do the same job. Teh default behavior of TeeChart is to group all variables in the same legend without distinction.

Comment: It may require TeeChart Pro, but I find that most things are possible, once you find the right area to tweak. Use the chart editor and fiddle with it until you achieve your purpose. Then see what properties are being set, and you can set them programmatically too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can show multiple legends as shown in the *All Features\Welcome!\Miscellaneous\Legend\Multiple Legends* example or use the ExtraLegend tool as in the *All Features\Welcome!\Tools\Extra Legend Tool* at the new features demo included with the registered versions or available at http://www.steema.com/download/vcl.